# svyCreateTableOne - Round frequencies

Tags: r, printing

How to round off just the frequency to the nearest whole number?
I am aware of the `catDigits` argument in `print()` - but this also rounds off the percentage.

Data:

```
library(tableone)
library(survey)

set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  married = sample(c(1, 0), 100, replace = TRUE),
  nodegree = sample(c(1, 0), 100, replace = TRUE),
  age = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 10),
  treat = rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.3),
  weight = 0  # initialize the weight variable
)
data$weight[data$treat == 1] <- runif(sum(data$treat == 1), min = 0.03, max = 0.87)
data$weight[data$treat == 0] <- runif(sum(data$treat == 0), min = 0.03, max = 0.87)
```

Creating the table:

```
datasvy <- survey::svydesign(~1, data = data,
                                strata = ~treat,
                                weights = ~weight)

tab1 <- svyCreateTableOne(vars = c("married", "nodegree"),
                          strata = "treat",
                          data = datasvy,
                          factorVars = c("married", "nodegree"))
```

```
> tab1 
                  Stratified by treat
                   0            1            p      test
  n                35.8         10.8                    
  married = 1 (%)  21.5 (60.3)   5.5 (51.0)   0.469     
  nodegree = 1 (%) 16.7 (46.7)   4.9 (45.6)   0.934
```

I expect the following:

```
> tab1 
                  Stratified by treat
                   0            1            p      test
  n                36           11                   
  married = 1 (%)  22 (60.3)    6 (51.0)   0.469     
  nodegree = 1 (%) 17 (46.7)    5 (45.6)   0.934
```

-----UPDATE:

```
vars <- c("married", "nodegree")

for (i in 1:length(tab1$CatTable)) {
  for (var in vars) {
    # Round 'freq' column
    tab1$CatTable[[i]][[var]]$freq <- round(tab1$CatTable[[i]][[var]]$freq)
    
    # Round 'n' column
    tab1$CatTable[[i]][[var]]$n <- round(tab1$CatTable[[i]][[var]]$n)
  }
}
```

But it rounds with one decimal place like `22.0` which is not an enrichment as the table is to be exported.

Comment: related issues: https://github.com/kaz-yos/tableone/issues/78, https://github.com/kaz-yos/tableone/issues/95

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The {tableone} printing functions do not have this feature incorporated that you are looking for. In fact, they oppress it.

#### Details

One could yield your desired result via the `nsmall` argument of `format()`:

```
format(1.567, nsmall = 1, digits = 1)
#> [1] "1.6"
format(1.567, nsmall = 0, digits = 1)
#> [1] "2"
```

However, in both, the internal functions [`print.svyCatTable`](https://github.com/kaz-yos/tableone/blob/e2e7cccdc8b9d51c8cb2bb1da91f4663bed5e128/R/print.svyCatTable.R#L89) and [`ModuleFormatNumericVector`](https://github.com/kaz-yos/tableone/blob/e2e7cccdc8b9d51c8cb2bb1da91f4663bed5e128/R/modules-print.R#L71), we can find the following line:

```
formatOptions$nsmall <- digits
```

Hence, even if we provide `nsmall` via `formatOptions`, it would be overridden. Additionally, `0` is not a valid value for digits:

```
format(1.567, digits = 0)
#> Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x): invalid value 0 for 'digits' argument
```

#### Options

Spoiler alert: probably none of them are really satisfactory for you

- write your own printing function
- fork the project, adjust the corresponding lines, and move on from there
- raise an issue/make a pull request and wait until it's incorporated (if they will)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `gtsummary` to modify the formats and output and do not have to write your own custom functions.
The table below stratifies by treatment, removes age and weight from output, formats count digits to 0 and percents to 1 digit, adds a p-value and formats it to 3 places. You can export this to html, pdf, or word with further customization.

```
library(gtsummary)
tbl_svysummary(datasvy, by = treat, 
               include = c(-age, - weight),
               digits = (all_categorical()~ c(0,1)) ) %>% 
  add_p(pvalue_fun = function(x){style_pvalue(x, digits = 3)})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am familiar with the gtsummary option. export to csv is also possible.

Comment: no problem and if there is also something I missed that is a requirement for you table I am happy to try and add it.